# SharePoint Online vs On Premises

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

What are the advantages/ disadvantages of using SharePoint Online vs On Premise? I want to inform one of my clients and convince as they are interested in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Google-Fu [will](http://blog.technovert.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-online-vs-premise-its-time-call/) return [many](http://www.enpointe.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-on-premise-office-365-sharepoint-online) different [articles](http://www.findwise.com/blog/search-within-cloud-and-on-premise-sharepoint-2013/).  These are a few of the more recent comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a very loaded question, and not knowing their environment I cant give all the advantages/disadvantages.

Because of its nature, SharePoint Online has many advantages:

- Easy to get up and running
- Better performance
- More reliability
- Easier to admin
- Capital Expense is much lower

The disadvantages:

- Unless you have Office 365 federated with your on premises AD, the
  users accounts don't sync.
- Expandability is limited, if there is a need to do something the
  isn't out of the box, it just cant be done.
- You cannot easily migrate from SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2013.

SharePoint 2013 Advantages:

- Unlimited scalability
- Unlimited options when it comes to add-ons, extra features, solutions, and development.
- Easy active directory integration for SSO.
- Granular control over every aspect.
- Sites can be easily migrated.

Disadvantages

- Difficult to get up and running.
- Difficult to admin properly.
- Large capital expense for the servers and licenses required,
- Steep learning curve
- Additional servers required for features that are available in SP Online

This is by no means an all encompassing list, just a few highlights from my experience. What it boils down to is SP Online is much easier to get started with, and for most cases will do everything the client needs. SP 2013 has a lot more expandability and flexibility, but is a much larger investment in terms of money, manpower and knowledge.